# JSF commandButton does not navigate to its action method's resulting page

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

**The goal:** The user enters in an email address. The submit button's action method checks for any existing emails in the database that are the same as the one entered. 
If there is a duplicate then the registration.xhtml page reloads. 
If there isn't a duplicate, then the userHome.xhtml page loads.

**The issue:** nothing happens when the submit button is clicked.

I do not receive any errors in the console, so I'm thinking it has to be some misplaced logic.

**Side Note:**There is an index.xhtml and web.xml page that I didn't include. Didn't think it was necessary to solve the problem. If you need them, then I will be glad to provide them.

registration.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 

    <h1>Welcome to the Registration Page</h1>

    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p>Username:</p><h:inputText value="#{user.name}" />
        <p>Email Address:</p><h:inputText value="#{user.email}"/>
        <p>Email Confirmation:</p><h:inputText value="#{user.emailConf}"/>
        <p>Password:</p><h:inputText value="#{user.password}"/>
        <p>Password Confirmation:</p><h:inputText value="#{user.passwordConf}"/>
        <p>Gender:</p><h:selectOneRadio id ="genderSelection" value="#{user.gender}">
                <f:selectItem id="male" itemLabel="Male" itemValue="male" />
                <f:selectItem id="female" itemLabel="Female" itemValue="female" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        <p>Birthday yy</p><h:inputText value="#{user.age}"/>

        <h:commandButton action="#{user.getEmailDuplicateResults}" value="Submit"/>

    </h:form>

</body> 
</html>
```

userHome.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 

    <h:message title="Welcome to the userHome page"/>
    <h1>Welcome to the userHome page2</h1>

</body> 
</html>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <navigation-rule>

        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{navigationClass.goToUserHome}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/userHome.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{navigationClass.goToRegistration}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{user.getEmailDuplicateResults}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>registration</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/registration.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{user.getEmailDuplicateResults}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>userHome</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/userHome.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>

    </navigation-rule>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>registrationView.User</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

User.java

```
package registrationView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "user")
@RequestScoped
public class User
{

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String emailConf;
    private String emailDatabaseTest;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConf;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private byte[] profileImage;
    private boolean isValidEmail = false;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmailConf()
    {
        return emailConf;
    }

    public void setEmailConf(String emailConf)
    {
        this.emailConf = emailConf;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConf()
    {
        return passwordConf;
    }

    public void setPasswordConf(String passwordConf)
    {
        this.passwordConf = passwordConf;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public byte[] getProfileImage()
    {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(byte[] profileImage)
    {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public boolean getValidEmail()
    {

        return isValidEmail;
    }

    public void setValidEmail(boolean valid)
    {

        this.isValidEmail = valid;
    }

    public String getEmailDuplicateResults()
    {
        checkForDuplicates();

        if (getValidEmail() == true)
        {
            return "userHome";
        } else
        {
            return "registration";
        }
    }

    public void checkForDuplicates()
    {
        // Create connection
        try
        {
            // Load driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Connect to the database
            Connection connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/userProfile?user=root&password=weston");
            // Set autocommit to false to manage it by hand
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            // Create the prepared statement object
            PreparedStatement statement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE email ='"
                            + getEmail() + "';");

            // assigning the query to a result set
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

            // testing result set made from queries for text or if it is empty
            while (rs.next())
            {

                emailDatabaseTest = rs.getString("email");

                if (emailDatabaseTest.isEmpty())
                {
                    isValidEmail = true;
                    setValidEmail(isValidEmail);
                } else
                {
                    isValidEmail = false;
                    setValidEmail(isValidEmail);
                }
            }

            rs.close();

            // Commit & close
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            // create message for unsuccessful loading

        }

    }

}
```

NavigationClass.java

```
package nav;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "navigationClass", eager = true)
@RequestScoped
public class NavigationClass implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String goToUserHome()
    {
        return "userHome";
    }

    public String goToRegistration()
    {
        return "registration";
    }

}
```

Comment: let's start using `<h:body>` rather than `<body>`

Comment: Also, when using a `PreparedStatement` you should pass in input as _bind variables_ (using the `?` placeholders in the query). Your current version is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: VoodooCoder, changing <body> to <h:body> didn't work, and thank you for the heads up Mick Mnemonic.

Comment: Your implementation looks odd to me. You've declared a `navigationClass` bean, but you never use it. You use `faces-config.xml` rules to define explicit navigation cases, but then you use implicit navigation rules in the backing bean. Unless you're using JSF 1.2, I wouldn't define any navigation rules in `faces-config.xml`, and use implicit navigation instead.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the explicit navigation rules you've defined in `faces-config.xml` are interfering with the implicit navigation rules you're using in `user`, as the logic isn't equivalent and XML configuration unusually overrides other types.

Comment: Hey DavidS, I had no idea explicit navigation was outdated. I read a bit online about implicit navigation, and it definitely seems like the the way to go like you noted. That said, I got rid of the navigationClass.java as well as the tags in the faces-config.xml file. However, it doesn't seem like the getEmailDuplicateResults() method is returning either of the string values "registration" or "userHome". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that instead "emailDatabaseTest.isEmpty()", using "emailDatabaseText == null" works.

Here is the code for anyone that runs into the problem in the future:

```java
package registrationView;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "user" ,eager = true)
@RequestScoped
public class User implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String emailConf;
    private String emailDatabaseTest;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConf;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private byte[] profileImage;
    private boolean isValidEmail = false;

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement prst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;




    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmailConf()
    {
        return emailConf;
    }

    public void setEmailConf(String emailConf)
    {
        this.emailConf = emailConf;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConf()
    {
        return passwordConf;
    }

    public void setPasswordConf(String passwordConf)
    {
        this.passwordConf = passwordConf;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public byte[] getProfileImage()
    {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(byte[] profileImage)
    {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public boolean getValidEmail()
    {

        return isValidEmail;
    }

    public void setValidEmail(boolean valid)
    {

        this.isValidEmail = valid;
    }

    public String getEmailDuplicateResults()
    {
        checkForDuplicates();

        if (getValidEmail() == true)
        {
            return "userHome";
        } else
        {
            return "registration";
        }
    }

    public void checkForDuplicates()
    {
        // Create connection
        try
        {
            // Load driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Connect to the database
            con = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/userProfile?user=root&password=weston");

            System.out.println("Connected to database userProfile!");
            // Set autocommit to false to manage it by hand
            //con.setAutoCommit(false); THIS IS SET TO AUTOCOMMIT SINCE 
            //THE ONLY QUERY IS TO CHECK THE DATABASE FOR A VALUE

            //query string to check database for email address entered
            String emailDuplicateCheckQuery = "SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE email =?; ";


            // Create the prepared statement object
            prst = con
                    .prepareStatement(emailDuplicateCheckQuery);

            //sets a string to the ? in the emailDuplicateCheckQuery query
            prst.setString(1, getEmail());

            // assigning the query to a result set
            rs = prst.executeQuery();


            // testing result set made from queries for text or if it is empty
            while (rs.next())
            {

                emailDatabaseTest = rs.getString("email");
                System.out.println(emailDatabaseTest);

            }

            if (emailDatabaseTest == null)
            {
                isValidEmail = true;
                setValidEmail(isValidEmail);
                System.out.println("Email is valid.");
            } else
            {
                isValidEmail = false;
                setValidEmail(isValidEmail);
                System.out.println("Email is invalid.");
            }



            rs.close();

            // Commit & close
            //con.commit();
            con.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            // create message for unsuccessful loading

        }

    }

}
```